# How can I 301 redirect all traffic from one URL pattern to another?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, seo

I’ve been grappling with a basic rewrite rule as we’ve changed a template name from template-a to template-b and need to 301 all links to the new template-b URLs. Example:

> /trusted-installers/template-a/something-here/and-possibly-here

Should be 301 redirected to:

> /trusted-installers/template-b/something-here/and-possibly-here

I know I need a pattern match and R=301 but so far I’ve not got this to work quite right. Any quick suggestions would be very gladly received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/trusted\-installers/template\-a/(.*)$ /trusted-installers/template-b/$1 [R=301]
```